# Resample DataFrame with DatetimeIndex and keep date range

Tags: python, pandas

My problem might sound trivial but I haven't found any solution for it:

I want the resampled data to remain in the same date range as the original data when I resample a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex e.g. into three-monthly values.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# data from 2014 to 2016
dim = 8760 * 3 + 24
idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2014 00:00:00', freq='h', periods=dim)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(dim, 2), index=idx)

# resample two three months
df = df.resample('3M').sum()
print(df)
```

yielding

```
                     0           1
2014-01-31   24.546928  -16.082389
2014-04-30  -52.966507  -40.255773
2014-07-31  -32.580114   47.096810
2014-10-31   -9.501333   12.872683
2015-01-31 -106.504047   45.082733
2015-04-30  -34.230358   70.508420
2015-07-31  -35.916497  104.930101
2015-10-31  -16.780425   17.411410
2016-01-31   68.512994  -43.772082
2016-04-30   -0.349917   27.794895
2016-07-31  -30.408862  -18.182486
2016-10-31  -97.355730 -105.961101
2017-01-31   -7.221361   40.037358
```

Why does the resampling exceed the date range e.g. create an entry for `2017-01-31` and how can I prevent this and instead remain within the original range e.g. between `2014-01-01` and `2016-12-31`? And shouldn't this be the expected standard behaviour going from `January-March, April-June, ... October-December`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be you need to stop the resampling after 2016-10-31. You are resampling for every three months and now to have another 3months resampling it goes beyond your date range.

Comment: But this would omit values, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes it would omit if you are using 3 months. But if there are no three months left to re sample, then you can stop your resampling right there and for those extra two months, you can use different resampling criteria

Comment: As explained in the comment of the answer below, shouldn't it be a two- or three-liner to resample between the range? The default behaviour does not make sense to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 36 months in your DataFrame.

When you resample every 3 months, the first row will contain everything up to the end of your first month, the second row will contain everything between your second month and 3 months after that, and so on. Your last row will contain everything from `2016-10-31` until 3 months after that, which is `2017-01-31`.

If you want, you could change it to

```
df.resample('3M', closed='left', label='left').sum()
```

, giving you

```
2013-10-31   3.705955  25.394287
2014-01-31  38.778872 -12.655323
2014-04-30  10.382832 -64.649173
2014-07-31  66.939190  31.966008
2014-10-31 -39.453572  27.431183
2015-01-31  66.436348  29.585436
2015-04-30  78.731608 -25.150526
2015-07-31  14.493226  -5.842421
2015-10-31  -2.394419  58.017105
2016-01-31 -36.295499 -14.542251
2016-04-30  69.794101  62.572736
2016-07-31  76.600558 -17.706111
2016-10-31 -68.842328 -32.723581
```

, but then the first row would be 'outside your range'.

If you resample every 3 months, then either your first row is going to be outside your range, or your last one is.

EDIT

If you want the bins to be 'first three months', 'next three months', and so on, you could write

```
df.resample('3MS').sum()
```

, as this will take the beginning of each month rather than its end (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still do not understand why it is not possible to resample within the data range when I have 36 months. Why does one resample have to lie outside the range? It could be Jan-Mar, April-June, July-September, October-December and so on for every year. Your solution works but is not exactly what I want and of which I do not understand why it ist not the standard case..

Comment: In other words: why does the first row contain everything up to the end of the first month and not to the third?

Comment: Because you're using 'M', which corresponds to 'month end frequency'. See my edit in my answer

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!